# Recognize this plane curve?

Tags: plane-geometry, algebraic-curves, reference-request

An aspect of my work led to a plane curve with implicit equation
$$
x^2+y^2 = 3 (y/2)^{2/3} + 1
$$
Actually, I started with the parametrization below and derived from it the
equation above:
\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& t (3-2 t^2) \\
y(t) &=& 2(1-t^2)^{3/2}
\end{eqnarray}

Here is what it looks like:

          
[image: Plots]

If this falls in some classical class of curves, and perhaps even has a name, 
I would like to reference it appropriately.
Does anyone recognize this curve?
Thanks!

**Answered**. By Sylvain Bonnot and Francesco Polizzi: It is a type of *nephroid*!
Here's the Wikipedia image from the article they both cited:

          [image: Wiki image]

Comment: It is almost a nephroid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephroid ), except I can't exactly make the reparametrization right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your curve is a *nephroid*, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephroid.

The general equation of such a plane curve is $$(x^2+y^2-4a^2)^3=108a^4y^2.$$ Your example corresponds to the value $a=\frac{1}{2}$ of the parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty curve...I think it is a Nephroid:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephroid